# typescript global variables across files

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables

In nodejs you are able to set `/* index.js file */ global.hello = 'hello'` and if you require another file after the statement the hello variable is valuable also there.

```
//index.js
global.hello = 'hi'
require('./other.js')

//other.js
console.log(hello) //returns hi
```

Is there an equivalent expression that can achieve the same result in typescript?

Comment: You should use a property if you need to share a variable with child components.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea. You can't ensure type safety with that. Instead, you can just import the variable. Or wrap console to a function and call it with different params (depending on usage).